# Consuming Secure rest services in Spring

Tags: spring, rest, model-view-controller, service

I have to consume one secured rest service where i initially pass credentials to service and it will return token,for subsequent requests i have to pass that generated token.How to implement these functionality in springs?

Answer (score 2):

For consume rest service you can use [`RestTemplate`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html)

**1.Simple solutions** if you already have token:

```
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.set("Authorization", "Bearer " + token); // add auth header with token
HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>(headers);
restTemplate.exchange("URL",HttpMethod.GET,entity,Object.class);
```

**2. Or better solution** is using `ClientHttpRequestInterceptor`. You create new `RestTemplate` and add you own interceptor, which will be getting token and setting to `headers`.

Simple example with [BasicAuth](http://www.baeldung.com/how-to-use-resttemplate-with-basic-authentication-in-spring)